# Add html toggle button PrimeNG p-editor

Tags: angular7, primeng, quill

I have added PrimeNG p-editor on my angular 7 application but wanted to add custom button to toggle on HTML and text view as this feature is not supported by primeNG/quill. Also went through this issue thread https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/128 but unable to find out the required answer.

I looked into multiple examples like
https://jsfiddle.net/nzolore/1jxy58vn/ and https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyEjrQ but all this is in javascript and unable to convert it in angular.

I have added `<button class="ql-edit-html">html</button>` under `<p-header>` but not getting next part.

any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem one week ago. Maybe we didn't fix it as you wanted. It's some kind of workaround.

We've added button under p-editor which is replacing quill with normal textArea.